# Gradle not generating a signed APK anymore

Tags: android, gradle, apk

I have been generating signed APKs in Android Studio (Build -> Generate Signed APK) for some time, but this morning I tried to create one from the command prompt (Windows) using the command:
`gradlew assembleRelease`

I cancelled the execution of this after a long period of time, as it appeared to have gotten stuck while unzipping the Grade files.

After this, I could no longer generate signed APKs in Android Studio, nor could I do so using the command above.

Instead only `app-release.apk` gets generated in the `/app/build/outputs/apk/`

The strange thing is, there isn't any error I can see, even when I add the --info or --debug flag to the command above, e.g. here are the last number of lines produced from executing `gradlew assembleRelease --info`:

```
:app:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:processReleaseJavaRes (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 0.002 secs.
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease (Thread[main,5,main]) started.
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease
Skipping task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease' as it is up-to-date (took 0.011 secs).
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 0.013 secs.
:app:validateSigningRelease (Thread[main,5,main]) started.
:app:validateSigningRelease
Executing task ':app:validateSigningRelease' (up-to-date check took 0.0 secs) due to:
  Task has not declared any outputs.
:app:validateSigningRelease (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 0.001 secs.
:app:packageRelease (Thread[main,5,main]) started.
:app:packageRelease
Executing task ':app:packageRelease' (up-to-date check took 0.024 secs) due to:
  Value of input property 'signingConfig.class' has changed for task ':app:packageRelease'
All input files are considered out-of-date for incremental task ':app:packageRelease'.
Unable do incremental execution: full task run
:app:packageRelease (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 2.284 secs.
:app:assembleRelease (Thread[main,5,main]) started.
:app:assembleRelease
Skipping task ':app:assembleRelease' as it has no actions.
:app:assembleRelease (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 0.0 secs.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 18.828 secs
Stopped 0 compiler daemon(s).
```

These two lines look suspicious:

```
Executing task ':app:validateSigningRelease' (up-to-date check took 0.0 secs) due to:
Task has not declared any outputs.
```

...but apart from that, have no idea why the signed versions of the APKs are not being generated.

I have looked at perhaps every Stackoverflow question and nothing has worked so far for me yet. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

For example the following `build.gradle` instructions works without a significant error message:

```
android {
    ...
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("release.keystore")
            keyAlias      "myalias"
            storePassword "xxxxxx"
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

But this is not sufficient. Here the `keyPassword` is missing. You need the complete instruction set:

```
android {
    ...
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("release.keystore")
            keyAlias      "myalias"
            storePassword "xxxxxx"
            keyPassword   "xxxxxx"
        }
    }
    ...
}
```